# Ionic 3 weatherapp access a variable from different tabs

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I recently got interested in programming an app. I want to create a weather app. The app should show the current weather using an API (openweathermap.org). There are 3 tabs in my app:

- The first tab (Home) should show the data.
- The second tab is for information about the creators (credits, useless)
- and the third tab is about logic.

Here's the difficulty: I have an Ionic-"**Select**"-element in my third tab. There you can choose one of 4 locations (which are already determined). Depending on which location is selected, the temperature of this location is shown on the first tab. Here's an example:

There are 4 locations ("Zwettl", "Krems", "St. Pölten" and "Wien"). If I choose Zwettl, the current temperature of the city "Zwettl" should be shown on the first tab.

- [First Tab, where the temperature should be shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG30A.png)
- [Third Tab, 'ion-select' for selecting a location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYeKw.png)
- [Selectable Locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oAiq.png)

Here's what I would like to know: how can I define the value of the location by selecting an 'ion-option' and how can I access this variable on the first tab (or in the tab1.page.ts).

You can ignore the checkboxes in picture 2, because I'm trying to define **what** to show on the first tab (temperature, humidity, ...) **after** the access from tab1 to tab3 works. I hope you know what I mean!

Here's the code I already have:

Tab1.html:

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-item>    
    <ion-label>
      <p id="weatherdata"></p>
      <h3>{{weather?.main.temp}}°C</h3>
      <ion-button (click)="setLocation1()">Zwettl</ion-button>
      <ion-button (click)="setLocation2()">Wien</ion-button>
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

Tab1.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './../api.service'
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss'],
})

export class Tab1Page {
  currentDate;
  weather: any;

  constructor(public api: ApiService) {
    this.currentDate = new Date();
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.api.loc = "Zwettl";
    this.getWeather();
  }

  setLocation1(){
    this.api.loc = "Zwettl";
    console.log(this.api.loc);
    this.getWeather();
  }

  setLocation2(){
    this.api.loc = "Wien";
    console.log(this.api.loc);
    this.getWeather();

  }

  async getWeather(){
    await this.api.getWeatherData().subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.weather = res;

    }, err => {console.log(err);
    });
  }  
}
```

Tab3.html:

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Settings  
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="compass"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label style="padding-left:15px">Location</ion-label>
      <ion-select placeholder="Select One">
        <ion-select-option value="zwettl">Zwettl</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="krems">Krems</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="stpoelten">St. Pölten</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="wien">Wien</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

API.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, of, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import{catchError, tap, map} from 'rxjs/operators';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type' : 'application/json'})
};
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  loc:any;


  getWeatherData(): Observable<any>{
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type' : 'application/json'})
    };
    const request = this.http.request<any>('GET', "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+this.loc+"&APPID=99b52e0a2655a753716cf6adb17476a7&units=metric")

            request.subscribe(response => {
                /Handling the response body/
            }, error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
            return request.pipe()

  }
}
```

And nothing important in Tab3.ts :(

Answer (score 0):

Use rxjs subject to define observable value anywhere in application

Define a service to set and get the observable value

Global-foo.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GlobalFooService {

  constructor() { }

  private fooSubject = new Subject<any>();

  publishSomeData(data: any) {
    this.fooSubject.next(data);
  }

  getObservable(): Subject<any> {
    return this.fooSubject;
  }
}
```

Tab3.ts

```
this.globalFooService.publishSomeData({
      foo: 'bar'
    });
```

Tab1.ts

```
this.globalFooService.getObservable().subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, gonna try this! :)